# Jenkins Conditional Stages

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I am using Declarative Jenkins pipeline. I have a stage where I get the input from the user like

```
//Input 
    stage ('Manual Input'){
        agent none
        steps {
            input message: "Please Approve", ok: 'Approve'
        }
    }
```

I do not want any agent to be held up while Jenkins is waiting for the Manual Step to complete, so I used `agent none`.

I want to know if there is a way, that this stage executes conditionally.

Elaborating on this:

```
pipeline {
agent none

parameters {
    choice(choices: "No\nYes",
        description: 'Choose Yes to wait for Manual Input',
        name: 'Input')
}
stages {

    stage ('Stage_1'){
        agent any
        steps {
           //Some Steps here
        }
    }

    //Input stage which should only get executed if ${Input} is Yes
    // Or else Directly go to Stage 3

    stage ('Manual Input'){
        agent none
        steps {
            input message: "Please Approve", ok: 'Approve'
        }
    }

stage ('Stage_3'){
        agent any
        steps {
           //Some Steps here
        }
    }
}
}
```

I want Jenkins to execute "Stage_1", then execute Stage "Manual Input" only if the parameter "Input" is "Yes" or else skip the stage "Manual Input" and go to "Stage_3".

I cannot execute `if/else` in `script{}` block in the stage "Manual Input" because of `agent none`. It throws an error.

Your help is much appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, all you have to do is to add a `when` statement in your second stage, you want it to look like this:

```
stage ('Manual Input'){
    agent none
    when{
        expression { params.Input == 'Yes' }
    }
    steps {
        input message: "Please Approve", ok: 'Approve'
    }
}
```

You can find documentation on this [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when). (You will see that, for this specific case, `equals` is more appropriate)